# Angular 2 change detection on iOS devices vs desktop/android

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome, angular2-changedetection

Are there any differences in Angular change detection between iOS mobile browsers (Safari, Chrome) and desktop/android Chrome?

I have just served my Angular application using http-server npm package (via webpack). On android device application works just fine. On Desktop as well.

But there are some problems on iOS web browsers. Data that are fetched asynchronously are not being displayed. ChangeDetectorRef nor NgZone don't change anything. Also, in several cases `?.` operator does not work.

Is anyone aware of any common pitfalls with Angular on iOS?

Comment: I am seeing the same with my app on 11.3 iOS and all works great on other devices

Comment: same problem, when the browser tab is clicked, the detection happens.